# Script for getting IP address of visitor is not working

Tags: php, mysql, http, ip-address

I am manually storing the below line in mysql database using php myadmin.

```
<div>IP address : '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>'</div>
```

It gets updated as I have confirmed it is in database.
My php page fetches this from database and updates the html.

The output that I get is -
`IP address :`

I am not an expert in php. Also I cannot write <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?> directly into my php page. Please help and tell me where is wrong.

Comment: Show us full code that stores data to the Db

Comment: Am I understanding right, you are storing `<div>IP address : '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']?>'</div>` in your database?

Comment: modified the question. Please refer that. I am not using any insert queries.

Comment: If you know it's getting stored correctly, can you show us how you are displaying it?

Comment: @Ash that won't work! You need to store the actual *result* of the function call in the data base

Comment: why not store the IP itself and not the whole string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you fetch the text from the DB and output it to the client, it will just be WRITTEN, not EXECUTED - so

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

will never be replaced by the real IP adsress.

A solution would be to store

```
<div>IP address : '%s'</div>
```

in your DB, later fetch it and

```
echo sprintf($txtfromdb,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

to your client.

Comment: Or just printf (echo sprintf is a bit redundant).

Comment: Principally I stand corrected. What I had in my (subconcious) mind with eth sprintf() was, that you might want to use the result in some template parsing stuff or similar, not directly throw it at the client.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store the Variables name as such in the database. Because the content of them won't be saved, only its name.

If you want the current clients IP to be shown you could (as for every php content to execute) eval it.

```php
ob_start();
eval( $the_table_content );
$the_content = ob_get_clean();
```

Now your right content is stored in `$the_content` and can for example be output by `echo $the_content`

But if you only want to output it, you don't need the above code and could try just `eval( $the_table_content )` instead of `echo $the_table_content`

A better solution is generally Eugen Riecks but in a few cases this is the fastest and easiest.